# how to show "Always allow" option in location permission [iOS] Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

My app fetches user's current location in the background and when app is in killed state.

So it needs **"Always allow"** permission level for this, but in iOS I am getting only two options, **"Allow once"** and **"While in use"**.

I am using [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/) package for requesting permission;

```
 PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
```

but still, it's **not** showing "always allow" option.
[image]

This issue only in iOS. In Android, everything works ok.

Comment: This is how Apple has decided to change the behavior of location permissions starting with iOS 13+. This article might help explain what's happening => https://medium.com/swlh/location-permission-in-ios-13-f9e10917c05e

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the documentation of [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) says:

> The locationAlways permission can not be requested directly, the user has to request the locationWhenInUse permission first. Accepting this permission by clicking on the 'Allow While Using App' gives the user the possibility to request the locationAlways permission. This will then bring up another permission popup asking you to Keep Only While Using or to Change To Always Allow.

And that's the reason why is not appearing in the first dialog.

Now, in order to show the second dialog where you can ask user for **always allow**, you have to ask for permission When in use, and then, validating the status, ask for the second permission

You can do something like this:

```
    var status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;
if(!status.isGranted){
  var status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
  if(status.isGranted){
    var status = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
    if(status.isGranted){
      //Do some stuff
    }else{
      //Do another stuff
    }
  }else{
    //The user deny the permission
  }
  if(status.isPermanentlyDenied){
    //When the user previously rejected the permission and select never ask again
    //Open the screen of settings
    bool res = await openAppSettings();
  }
}else{
  //In use is available, check the always in use
  var status = await Permission.locationAlways.status;
  if(!status.isGranted){
    var status = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
    if(status.isGranted){
      //Do some stuff
    }else{
      //Do another stuff
    }
  }else{
    //previously available, do some stuff or nothing
  }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: This deserves a lot of upvotes! Thanks friend, really helped me

Comment: var status = await Permission.locationAlways.request(); Is not waiting for the result.